# SSRS Chart filter returning no data when using *.*

Tags: reporting-services, wildcard, period

I have been trying to get a filter to work on SSRS on a chart for the past hour however I am seeing some strange results.

If I specify my expression as the below I get no data found:

`"*.*"+"@domain.com"`

If I specify the below I get results matching people starting with those letters:

`"l*.g*"+"@domain.com"`

I have also tried the below with no results unless I include the first letter of the names as well.

`"*"+"."+"*"+"@domain.com"`

Lastly I also tried the below to start with and returned no results:

`"*.*@domain.com"`

I am guessing that the `.` on it's own affects the filter somehow. I tried using the `Chr(46)` method for the `.` instead but still returning no results.

I'm at a bit of a loss as I can't find any information that would suggest which this would present the results I'm seeing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you need to filter field values that starts with any number of characters followed by a dot then any number of characters followed by @domain.com Did you try: `"*.*@domain.com"` ?

Comment: Yes - it's basically an e-mail in the format of firstname.lastname@domain.com. The part where I said "lastly I tried", I think it took out my formatting as it was written as you have said and also returns no data however l*.g*@domain.com does. It seems to only be an issue when the only character between the wildcards is the ..

Comment: Are you not able to do this filtering within your SQL query, using `like '%.%@domain.com'`?

Comment: The query I have already contains a number of filters and as I'm not a SQL expert by any means I was trying not to expand it further as I expected the chart filter to make a simple job of it however I may have to go that route by the look of it.

Comment: Maybe it was the lack of coffee last night that put me off but I have re-written the query as sub-queries and then joined together the information I need.